# How to get value from the MultiList Field and Get Path to Tag Repository

Tags: powershell-extensions

I have a little bit of confusion regarding the **Multilist Field** in Sitecore. Basically, I want to get all of the **selected MultiList Field** in PowerShell to do stuff with them.

Is it possible to make those values in **array**?

**Here is the code so far:**

```
$props = @{
    Title = "Get All Media Items by Tag"
    Description = "Get all Media items by Tag"
    OkButtonName = "Run Report"
    CancelButtonName = "Cancel"
    Parameters = @(
        @{ Name = "TagName"; Title = "Tag Name"; Editor = "multilist"; Source = "/sitecore/system/Settings/Buckets/TagRepository/2021/12/16/14/36" }
        @{ Title = "Note"; Value = "Select Tags you need for the Images from the Tag Repository"; Editor = "info" }
    )
}

$result = Read-Variable @props
if($result -ne "ok") {
    Close-Window
    Exit
}
```

The path for the **Tag Repositoy** is bucket, as you know. How to get also path for that?
`Source = "/sitecore/system/Settings/Buckets/TagRepository/2021/12/16/14/36" }`

**And this is the picture showing what this code does:**

[image]

Is there any way to get those **selected values** and make them in array, or they are in array by default?

I personally think maybe `$TagName.Values` would do the trick, or something like that

Answer (score 1):

You are correct with your approach. You just have a typo. Use `Name = "TagNames"` instead of `Name = "TagName"` in your props. Then you can use `$TagNames`:

```
$props = @{
    Title = "Get All Media Items by Tag"
    Description = "Get all Media items by Tag"
    OkButtonName = "Run Report"
    CancelButtonName = "Cancel"
    Parameters = @(
        @{ Name = "TagNames"; Title = "Tag Name"; Editor = "multilist"; Source = "/sitecore/system/Settings/Buckets/TagRepository/2021/12/16/14/36" }
        @{ Title = "Note"; Value = "Select Tags you need for the Images from the Tag Repository"; Editor = "info" }
    )
}

$result = Read-Variable @props

if($result -ne "ok") {
    Close-Window
    Exit
}

foreach ($tag in $TagNames) {
    # ... do whatever you need with your tag
}
```

Comment: Thank you this helped me. Do you have any tips how to get `Tagging` field in other items. Like beacuse it is MultiList field as well, but how to compare these two? Like from the Tag MultiList to the Item MultiList if they have same selected item name

Comment: @Samke11 you should keep 1 question inside 1 post. Best create a new question with screenshots from your system and marking what exactly you want to achieve and what you already have.